# SQL SUM() of distinct rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+------+----------+----------+--------+
|  id  |  team    |   match  |  score |
+------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1   |     1    |    1     |  10    |
|  2   |     2    |    1     |  5     |
|  3   |     1    |    1     |  5     |
|  4   |     1    |    2     |   6    |
|  5   |     2    |    1     |   4    |
+------+----------+----------+--------+
```

I need to calculate `SUM()` of all the scores for each individual match and team, I know how to calculate the sum...

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS team_a_score WHERE `match`='1'
```

I'd expect something like this...

```
+----------------+
| team_a_score   |
+----------------+
|    24          |
+----------------+
```

But what I actually need to happen is to get the score for team 1 and 2 separately so it would be more like this...

```
+----------------+----------------+
| team_a_score   |  team_b_score  |
+----------------+----------------+
|    15          |     9          |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
 SELECT team, SUM(score) AS team_a_score FROM some_table GROUP BY team
```

the result would not be in columns (as described in your questions) but in rows each one with the team number and the total score

```
+----------+---------------+
|  team    |   score       |
+----------+---------------+
|     1    |    15         |
|     2    |     9         |
```

Comment: @LeePrice you can add your `where` clause before the group by. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you want the results in the same row, so you would use this:

```
select sum(case when team = 1 then score end) team_a,
  sum(case when team = 2 then score end) team_b
from yourtable
where `match` = 1
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7e7b/5)

Answer (score -1):

Use `GROUP_BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS team_a_score WHERE `match`='1' GROUP_BY team
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT team,sum(score) AS team_score
FROM table_missed
WHERE `match`='1'
GROUP by team
```

Comment: all the answers have been downvoted by a mysterious serial downvoter.. :-/  i'll upvote all of them to compensate..

Comment: @jidma I am guessing the downvotes are due to the fact that answers are not even valid SQL syntax.  There are no `FROM` clauses on most of the answers including the accepted one.

Comment: They also don't produce the correct results - two scores on a single row. Doesn't seem like that's important to the OP but technically most of the answers on this page don't answer the question.

Comment: @bluefeet that's because even the question does not have `FROM` clause. The question was accepted as the asker got the idea and knows how to solve his problem, and i think anybody else with the same question will be able to solve his problem by looking at the answers, which is the main purpose of SO IMHO.

Comment: @jidma I disagree. New users will come across this question and be very confused why the accepted answer doesn't produce the desired results. Bluefeet's answer is the only one on this page that produces the expected output. It's great that the OP figured it out (we think), but no that's not the main purpose of SO. In addition to helping the OP solve problems, it's also to serve as the canonical place for other people to solve the same problems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand and that's what comments are there for. Putting a comment and letting the person know that they forgot something is a better solution than downvoting the question, i guess.

Comment: @jidma Unfortunately, as much as it stinks, anonymous voting is an essential component here. We'd love to get an explanation for every single down-vote, but it's just not going to happen. Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18677/how-do-i-know-what-the-down-votes-were-for

Comment: @AaronBertrand i agree sometimes the answer is just wrong and the downvoter does not need a comment to explain why. But sometimes it just needs some fixing.. anyhow, i fixed my answer and hope it is ok for you now.

Comment: @jidma the point isn't just that the answerer knows why - down-voters aren't trying intentionally to leave the answerer in the dark, they're just protecting themselves from vengeful behavior (and there have been many, many documented cases - I've been the victim myself). As for your answer, I didn't down-vote, but I still think it's incorrect. The OP asked for one row, with score a in column 1, and score b in column 2. As I said before, bluefeet's answer is the only one on this page that does this. Which is why I was surprised yours was the accepted answer (and others might be surprised too).

Comment: @jidma And just FYI up-voting incorrect answers to compensate for the issue that has clearly been identified does not help the site or future readers.

Comment: @AaronBertrand my answer has a limitation which i stated `the result will not be in columns`. Bigfoot's answer also has a limitation which is the number of teams we can have (it wouldn't work unless we know there are only two teams). The OP needs the sum for each team no matter how many teams there are, and the example he gave was just an example `it would be more like this...`. Anyway..

Comment: @AaronBertrand i upvoted question that seemed "correct" to me, not because they have been serially downvoted. I hope you see my point (and I do see yours).

Comment: Presumably a match is only ever between two teams. Just saying. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes but.. err.. a match .. sometimes .. err.. oh forget it you're right :)