# How to sum column values for each distinct value in another column

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a report for performance evaluation based on working time of personnel and the workstation. I manage to get all the information from the tables i need but i cant finalize the code to make it show as a single line. Here is what i use;

First i use these 2 selects so that i only have what i need as both of these tables have over 20-25 columns and a lot of rows;

```
SELECT CONFIRMATION, CONFIRMPOS, POTYPE, PRDORDER,
     OPERATION,PERSONELNUM,PERSONELNAME 
    FROM PERSONNEL 
    INTO TMPPERSONEL;

SELECT WORKCENTER, CONFIRMATION, CONFIRMPOS,SETUP,
     MACHINE, LABOUR, CONFIRMDATE 
    FROM CONF 
    INTO TMPCONF;
```

Next i use this select to combine the two tables to work on;

```
SELECT TMPPERSONNEL.POTYPE, TMPPERSONNEL.PRDORDER, TMPPERSONNEL.OPERATION, TMPCONF.WORKCENTER, TMPCONF.CONFIRMATION, TMPCONF.CONFIRMPOS, TMPPERSONNEL.PERSONELNUM, TMPPERSONNEL.PERSONELNAME, TMPCONF.SETUP, TMPCONF.MACHINE, TMPCONF.LABOUR, TMPCONF.CONFIRMDATE 
    FROM TMPPERSONNEL  LEFT JOIN TMPCONF ON  TMPCONF.CONFIRMATION = TMPPERSONNEL.CONFIRMATION 
        AND TMPCONF.CONFIRMPOS = TMPPERSONNEL.CONFIRMPOS 
    INTO TMPREPORT;
```

Now what i want to do is sum the time worked(SETUP,MACHINE,LABOUR) for each person or workstation between specific dates( DATE1,DATE2 ) and show it as a single line. For example from this table

```
PERSONELNUM  PERSONELNAME  WORKCENTER   SETUP  MACHINE  LABOUR  CONFIRMDATE 
1             Personnel1   WORKCENTER1     5     20       20    01.01.2014
1             Personnel2   WORKCENTER1     5     20       20    01.01.2014
1             Personnel2   WORKCENTER3     5     20       20    02.01.2014
1             Personnel1   WORKCENTER2     5     20       20    02.01.2014
1             Personnel3   WORKCENTER1     5     20       20    02.01.2014
1             Personnel3   WORKCENTER2     5     20       20    03.01.2014
1             Personnel1   WORKCENTER1     5     20       20    03.01.2014
1             Personnel2   WORKCENTER3     5     20       20    04.01.2014
1             Personnel1   WORKCENTER2     5     20       20    04.01.2014
1             Personnel3   WORKCENTER1     5     20       20    04.01.2014
```

to

```
PERSONELNUM  PERSONELNAME  SETUP  MACHINE  LABOUR 
1             Personnel1     20     80       80  
2             Personnel2     15     60       60    
3             Personnel3     15     60       60
```

I am sorry if my explanation is confusing. As i am a beginner i can only describe the problem to the best of my small knowledge.

Edit: And what should i do if i want to see something like this:

```
PERSONELNUM  PERSONELNAME  WORKCENTER    SETUP  MACHINE  LABOUR 
  1          Personnel1    WORKCENTER1     10     40       40  
  1          Personnel1    WORKCENTER2     10     40       40 
  1          Personnel2    WORKCENTER1      5     20       20      
  1          Personnel2    WORKCENTER3     10     40       40 
  1          Personnel3    WORKCENTER1     10     40       40 
  1          Personnel3    WORKCENTER2      5     20       20
```

Comment: All those CAPS are QUITE MENACING!

Comment: sorry about the caps. i copy pasted from mySQL line :)

Comment: They're quite menacing there too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried grouping the personelnum column and summing the other columns?
something like:

```
SELECT p.POTYPE, p.PRDORDER, p.OPERATION, c.WORKCENTER, c.CONFIRMATION, c.CONFIRMPOS, p.PERSONELNUM, p.PERSONELNAME, sum(c.SETUP), sum(c.MACHINE), sum(c.LABOUR), c.CONFIRMDATE 
FROM TMPPERSONNEL as p LEFT JOIN TMPCONF as c ON c.CONFIRMATION = p.CONFIRMATION 
    AND c.CONFIRMPOS = p.CONFIRMPOS 
group by
    p.PERSONELNUM
 INTO TMPREPORT;
```

in order to add more than one group by column you must add each of them seperating by a comma

```
SELECT p.POTYPE, p.PRDORDER, p.OPERATION, c.WORKCENTER, c.CONFIRMATION, c.CONFIRMPOS, p.PERSONELNUM, p.PERSONELNAME, sum(c.SETUP), sum(c.MACHINE), sum(c.LABOUR), c.CONFIRMDATE 
FROM TMPPERSONNEL as p LEFT JOIN TMPCONF as c ON c.CONFIRMATION = p.CONFIRMATION 
    AND c.CONFIRMPOS = p.CONFIRMPOS 
group by
    p.PERSONELNUM, c.WORKCENTER
 INTO TMPREPORT;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487361/sql-sum-of-distinct-rows?rq=1)?

I've listed a possible solution below

```
SELECT PERSONELNUM, PERSONELNAME, SUM(SETUP),SUM(MACHINE),SUM(LABOUR) AS PERSONELNAME_SUM FROM TABLE GROUP BY PERSONELNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT
 PERSONALNUM,
 PERSONALNAME,
 SUM(SETUP) AS SETUP,
 SUM(MACHINE) AS MACHINE,
 SUM(LABOUR) AS LABOUR
FROM
 TMPREPORT
WHERE
 CONFIRMDATE BETWEEN 'DATE1' AND 'DATE2'
GROUP BY
 PERSONELNUM;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html